Where was Rosny Ainé's "The cataclysm" first published in English?
The short story "Le cataclysme" by J.H. Rosny Aîné was published in France in 1888, and apparantly (from ISFDB) was translated in English in 1896 with the title "The cataclysm". However, on ISFDB I found only the reference of the translation from B. Stableford in 2010.
Do you know in which medium (newspaper, book or somthing else) the 1896 English translation appeared? And if possible, if you have the reference, that would be really nice!

Some genre content appeared in non-genre publications, like Punch magazine.  Since the magazine is non-genre it isn't indexed by ISFDb, and that can mean missing entries for such works.  Sometimes the title page for the work will say "Originally published in Saturday Night, 1955" or something like that, but they don't do that for first translations.

@Valorum Both that page and the original title page give an 1896 date for the English translation.  It's a small piece of evidence, but internally consistent and distinct enough from the 2010 date of Stableford's work that it might be correct.

@DavidW - SFE doesn't have it in translation; https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/rosny_aine_j_h

@DavidW - Punch certainly had a genre. Its genre was satire.

Thanks for your comments ! Unfortunately, I don't have the Brian Stableford's translation in hands, so I can't verify in the book " The mysterious force and other anomalous phenomena" (https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?529139) if it is indicated (as a note or something like that). Maybe somebody who has the book could verify ?
